# Parsing command line inputs in C

Tags: c, parsing, token

So I have to create a unix like shell and filesystem. I am currently stuck on getting the program to accept the commands, such as ls, cd, stat, exit. Whenever "ls" is inputted, it just returns the printf line again. But if you do "ls l", it prints out "You entered ls", which is more or less what I want, but I don't need anything after ls. for the commands I listed above, I simply want just the command entered and no other spaces or characters needing to be entered. But if i use "cd", I want the program to be able to diferentiate the fact that some destination needs to be entered after the command, which I believe is working properly. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char cmd[50];
const char spc[50] = " ";
char *file, *dir;
char *tok, *nextName;


while(1){
    printf("Russ_John_Shell> ");
    fgets(cmd, 50, stdin);

    //Tokenizes string to determine what command was inputed as well as any file/directory name needed
    tok = strtok(cmd, spc);
    nextName = strtok(tok, spc);


    //Checks to see whether the string has a file/directory name after the command
    if (strcmp(cmd, tok) == 0){
        if (strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0){
            listDir(cmd);
        } else if (strcmp(cmd, "stat") == 0){
            status(cmd);
        } else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0){
            exitShell(cmd);
        }
    } else {
        if (strcmp(cmd, "cd") == 0){
            changeDir(cmd);
        } else if (strcmp(cmd, "mkdir") == 0){
            makeDir(cmd);
        } else if (strcmp(cmd, "mkfs") == 0){
            makeFS(cmd);
        } else if (strcmp(cmd, "rmdir") == 0){
            remDir(cmd);
        } else if (strcmp(cmd, "mkfile") == 0){
            makeFile(cmd);
        } else if (strcmp(cmd, "rmfile") == 0){
            remFile(cmd);
        } else {
            printf("Command %s not recognized.\n", "cmd");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what does a debugger show is happening? WHere does it go that you didnt expect?

Comment: `nextName = strtok(tok, spc);` ==> `nextName = strtok(NULL, spc);` unless you want to subdivide the first token with *different* delimiters. Also as you are using `fgets` I recommend you put `\n` in the delimiter set.

Comment: Okay so I'm using notepad++ and ubuntu terminal to do all this. I am new to C and I have no idea what to use as a debugger. Could list something I could possibly get? If i enter "ls" is supposed to list the files in the current directory. I"m not worried about the function of the command. It's just supposed to read the command and if it is a match in the if statement, it calls the function related to it, which for now all it does is print "You entered ls". To get that to work though, I have to enter "ls l" or "ls ". I want to eliminate the space needed after the command basically.